# Java screenshot with Robot ressource effectivity

Tags: java, awt, screenshot, awtrobot

Im writing a program in java which should take screenshots of different windows multiple times per second. It uses the `createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)`
from java.awt.Robot. I have thought of 2 different possible ways to do this:

1.: Take a screenshot of the area of each window.
 2.: Take a screenshot ofthe whole screen and then divide it in smaller images.

Which one is more ressource effective?

Comment: The one screen shot... but won't this have all of the window overlap issues?

Comment: No they will be next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device IO is the bottleneck here by leagues, so capture it once into memory, and then operate on that.